# Combine Data function

Tags: function, date

Beginner in writing queries,

I have the below table, which has order ID its start and end date, quantity and material.

```
OrderID Start Date      End Date        Quantity    Material
 1      4/5/2016 9:14   4/6/2016  7:00   5000           A
 2      3/30/2016 15:08 3/30/2016 19:09  120            B
 2      3/30/2016 19:09 3/30/2016 22:30  120            B
 3      4/4/2016 0:00   4/4/2016 0:00    46             C
 4      4/6/2016 21:42  4/7/2016 0:00    300            D
 5      4/2/2016 19:06  4/2/2016 21:51   123            E
 5      4/2/2016 21:51  4/4/2016 0:56    123            E
 5      4/4/2016 0:56   4/4/2016 5:05    123            E
```

For every order ID it has multiple start and end date, the reason is that when ever the machine is producing the order and stopping it logs.
I would like to combine all the order ID with Start Date as the beginning time and end as the last time logged. The material count is the same .

For example I would like a table like below,

```
OrderID Start Date      End Date       Quantity Material
1       4/5/2016 9:14   4/6/2016 7:00   5000      A
2       3/30/2016 15:08 3/30/2016 22:30 120       B
3       4/4/2016 0:00   4/4/2016 0:00   46        C
4       4/6/2016 21:42  4/7/2016 0:00   300       D
5       4/2/2016 19:06  4/4/2016 5:05   123       E
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by OrderID and get max, min, and other calculations (avg, sum, ...)

```
SELECT OrderID, min(start_date), max(start_date), quantity, material
FROM your_table
GROUP BY OrderID
```